# Which version of Firebase Auth support Authentication on android using phone number?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is build.gradle file. 
Currently using dependencies given below:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this version of firebase supports the phone authentication

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
```

I guess you should add this one to your gradle file and should work out of the box.

The latest one is give below.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
```

[Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) to guide